# Android Studio doesn't delete drawable resource from all drawable folders

Tags: android-studio

I don't know after which update I started to come across with this issue but when I delete a drawable resource from for example drawable-hdpi folder Android Studio doesn't delete the same named resource from other drawable folders.

Is there a settings to enable this again?

**Environments**

- Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1
- MacBook Pro, Ventura 13.0.1

Comment: You can just toggle your project tree to "Android" and then it combines all drawable sizes to one drawable folder. There you should be able to delete things at once and it should affect the others as well...

Comment: Yes, when the project tree is "Android" i am able to delete resource at once. But if project tree is "Project" it deletes one by one and i strongly prefer to use "Project" tree. Besides i was able to delete at once before.

Answer (score 0):

When switching the project editor to the `Android` mode, Android Studio clusters the drawable files into one folder so that you can delete all Files at once. Even though you loose some granularity when using the Android view, it greatly speeds up the process of deleting drawables.